# Event from external callback

Tags: c#, events, callback, invoke

I'm creating a project of data transmitter using custom DLL written in ANSI C. My aim is to send chunks of data, which each of them must be confirmed after sending by build in `OnDataSendingDone` callback.

The problem is that I have no idea how to hook that callback to an event, so I can wait for it after each `SendByte`. Maybe event is not such a good idea.

My question is: how to wait for the `OnDataSendingDone` callback after `SendByte`?

Please give me some clues. Here is the code snippet:

```
class LibWrapper
{
    [DllImport(dllPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "SetCallback")]
    public static extern bool SetCallback(byte functype, Delegate func);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void CallbackDelegate(UInt32 handle);

    private static CallbackDelegate OnDataSendingDone;

    public void OnDataSendingDoneCallback(CallbackDelegate callback)
    {
        OnDataSendingDone_ft = new CallbackDelegate2(callback);
        SetCallback(FT_DATASENDINGDONE, OnDataSendingDone_ft);
    }
}

class Transmitter
{
    LibWrapper lib = new LibWrapper();

    byte[] data = new byte[10];

    public void OnDataSendingDone(UInt32 handle)
    {
        return;
    }

    lib.OnDataSendingDoneCallback(OnDataSendingDone);

    public void TransmitData()
    {
        // here: sequential data transmission   
        foreach (byte b in data)
        {
            lib.SendByte(b);
            // here: wait for OnDataSendingDone
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could do something like this:

```
class Transmitter
{
    LibWrapper lib = new LibWrapper();
    private AutoResetEvent evt = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    byte[] data;

    public void OnDataSendingDone(UInt32 handle)
    {
        evt.Set();
    }

    public void TransmitData()
    {
        // here: sequential data transmission   
        foreach (byte b in data)
        {
            lib.SendByte(b);
            if (!evt.WaitOne(15000)) // or whatever timeout makes sense
                throw new Exception("timed out");
        }
    }
}
```